# How to validate length of a struct field using Min() or Max() rules in go-ozzo/ozzo-validation

Tags: validation, go

I think to pass threshold number to the Min() function, and expect that function to validate the `Name` length. However, it's not working.

Here below is my code:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (c Person) Validate() error {
    return validation.ValidateStruct(&c,
        validation.Field(&c.Name, validation.Min(5)),
    )
}

func main() {
    person := Person{
        Name: "Udin",
    }

    if err := person.Validate(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

After I see the [Min() validation rules test in documentation](https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/blob/master/minmax_test.go#L61), the correct way to use it is:

```
err := validation.Min(5).Validate(len(person.Name))
```

So, the question is, how to use that `Min()` rules in `validation.ValidateStruct()`?
Is that possible?

Comment: You should use `validation.Length(5, 0)` instead of `validation.Min(5)`, according to the lib repo [readme](https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation). `0` here means no validation for the max acceptable length.